# PHP - Closing off a div with nested loops

Tags: php, joomla

I have a folder with around 400 images. I'd like to put them on a page put only eight at a time. Meaning i will have all the images on the same page, but cut in sections of eight images wrapped in a box like this:

```html
<div class="eightbox">
 <img src="image1">
 <img src="image2">
 <img src="image3">
 <img src="image4">
 <img src="image5">
 <img src="image6">
 <img src="image7">
 <img src="image8">
</div>
<div class="eightbox">
 <img src="image9">
 <img src="image9">
 <img src="image10">
 <img src="image11">
 <img src="image12">
 <img src="image13">
 <img src="image14">
 <img src="image15">
</div>
```

Now my code for this so far makes an output, but does not close the "eightbox" so that every new div is inside the other one.

Here's my Code:

```html
<?php
$files = glob("images/*.*"); //loads all the images from my folder into an array

$y = ceil(count($files)/8); // The amount of images divided by eight and rounded up
$z = 1; //This counter makes the array continue outside the loop

for ($i=1; $i<$y; $i++)
{
 echo '<div class=\'eightbox\'>';
 
 for ($q=0; $q<8; $q++)
 {
  $num = $files[$z];
  echo '<img src=\'' . $num . '\' >';
  $z++;
 }
 
 echo '</div>';
}
?>
```

I hope this makes any sense to you and thanks in advance for helping!

EDIT: on popular demand heres a screenshot of the code i'm getting with chrome:
[Screenshot of my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DXjze.png)

Comment: `echo '<div class="eightbox">';`

Comment: Can you post the (the wrong) html you're getting?

Comment: http://occ.bruehlmann-anhaenger.ch/bildergallerie this is the output of my code

Comment: imho that is impossible. nothing wrong with your code. Probably you do not output directly to the browser, do you use any framework or templating system?

Comment: _“this is the output of my code”_ - there is not one single element with the class `eightbox` in the source code of that page …

Comment: @Alex i use Joomla and the code is inside a module wich is displayed inside an article...

Comment: @misorude there is for me if you look at my screenshot: [link](https://i.imgur.com/1ecWJLs.png)

Comment: @T.Roman please keep your page public soi we can see the real output of your code.

Comment: That’s not what I see in the source code. Are you loading this dynamically, via AJAX? Then the script error the browser console shows might be the reason I see no images whatsoever there.

Comment: please provide full fragment - what is that module is doing?  what phase it got executed, it seem very similar to that issue https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/issues/12784

Comment: @Alex I use the plugin [Sourcerer](https://extensions.joomla.org/extension/sourcerer/) to use php code inside a module

Comment: I think you should at least try to change your '<div></div>' to `<p></p>`. That is something related to Joomla article body filtering that triggers to filter your closing tag.

Comment: In plugin description it clearly said : **The only thing you have to do is surround the code with the Sourcerer tags.** I don't see that `Sourcerer` in your code.

Comment: @Alex i did put the {source} and {/source} in my code.. else it would not be working at all

Comment: @Alex Using a p tag rather than a div does not wrap the images at all, just puts out all the images...

Comment: if you did `{source}` - share the full fragment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An alternative which splits the files into chunks of 8 ( using [`array_chunk()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php)) and then outputs each chunk at a time...

```
$split = array_chunk($files, 8);
foreach ( $split as $div )  {
    echo '<div class=\'eightbox\'>';

    foreach ($div as $file )    {
        echo '<img src=\'' . $file . '\' />';
    }

    echo '</div>';
}
```

Or using `implode()` to output the data...

```
$split = array_chunk($files, 8);
foreach ( $split as $div )  {
     echo '<div class=\'eightbox\'><img src=\''.
          implode('\' /><img src=\'', $div).
          '\' /></div>';
}
```

which IMHO is a little less readable, but more compact.

Comment: This looks like a much cleaner code than my work! The Code gives me the same problem wich stated in my question above. Divs wrapped inside each other...

Comment: If you view the source, are the div's nested or separate?

Comment: nested as in "eightbox" inside "eightbox"

Comment: I can't seem to reproduce that, in my tests, they are all chunks of img tags in a div tag.

Comment: Dont get me wrong.. the images load fine but the div tags wich the images are in, are not next to each other...

Comment: Could this mean the layout (perhaps CSS) is the problem rather than the tags?

Comment: this is a rather interesting approach, but worth a look. My CSS: `.eightbox {
  width:100%;
}

.eightbox img {
  display: inline-block;
  width:20%;
  margin:2.5%;
}`

Answer (score 0):

Using Modulo you could do this

```
<?php

$files = glob("images/*.*"); //loads all the images from my folder into an array


foreach ( $files as $idx=>$file) {

    if ( $idx % 8 == 0 && $idx != 0){  // every 8 close a div and open a new one
        echo '</div>';
        echo '<div class="eightbox">';
    }
    if ( $idx == 0 ){  // output first div
        echo '<div class="eightbox">';
    }
    echo "<img src='$file'>";

}

if ( $idx+1 % 8 != 0 ) { // close the last div
    echo '</div>';
}
?>
```

Comment: Wouldn't the last `</div>` always need to be echoed?

Comment: Not if you had exactly 8 images in the last set. I made a minor amendment anyway please check